# I can't get data from multiple collections inside one backbone view using lodash _.template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, lodash

I trying to get data from `menusCollection` inside `productsView`. I'm trying to load data from multiple fetched collections in one backbone view. So I really struggling with that I will be very gratefull with any help.

**router.js:**

```
app_router.on('route:products', function() {
     var menusCollection = new MenusCollection();
     menusCollection.fetch();
     var productsCollection = new ProductsCollection();
     productsCollection.fetch({
         success: function () {
                 var productsView = new ProductsView({model:productsCollection.models},{menu:menusCollection.models});
                 productsView.render();
          }
      });
});
```

**ProductsView.js:**

```
var menusCollection = new MenusCollection();
var products = this.model;
var productsCollection = new ProductsCollection(products);
this.el.innerHTML =  _.template( productsTemplate, {data:  menusCollection.toJSON()});
```

then in **productsTemplate** I wanna render multiple colections like :

```
<% _.each( data, function( product, i ){ %>
    <%= product.product_title %>
<% }) %>

<% _.each( data, function( menu, i ){ %>
    <%= menu.menu_title %>
<% }) %>
```

My template is loaded but without data from collection. How Can I get it ?
Thanks a lot!

**EDITED, It is working but, it is good way to handle multiple collections in one view ?**

**router.js:**

```
app_router.on('route:products', function() {
    var menusCollection = new MenusCollection();
    menusCollection.fetch({
        success: function () {
               var productsCollection = new ProductsCollection();
               productsCollection.fetch({
                   success: function () {
                      var productsView = new ProductsView({model:productsCollection.models, collection:menusCollection.models});
                      productsView.render();
                    }
                 });
        }
    });
 });
```

or something like this ?

```
   app_router.on('route:products', function() {
       var menusCollection = new MenusCollection();
       var productsCollection = new ProductsCollection();
       $.when( menusCollection.fetch(), productsCollection.fetch() ).done(function () {
            var productsView = new ProductsView({model:productsCollection.models, collection:menusCollection.models});
            productsView.render();
        });

    });
```

**ProductsView.js:**

```
var products = this.model;
var menus = this.collection;
var menusCollection = new MenusCollection(menus);
var productsCollection = new ProductsCollection(products);
this.el.innerHTML =  _.template( productsTemplate, {data:  productsCollection.toJSON(), menus:  menusCollection.toJSON()});
```

**productsTemplate**

```
<% _.each( data, function( product, i ){ %>
    <%= product.product_title %>
<% }) %>

<% _.each( menus, function( menu, i ){ %>
    <%= menu.menu_title %>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: @muistooshort I have edited code... Do you mean like this? Is possible to render three collections in one view? Or it is completly bad idea ? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's a common XHR issue.
You have to wait until the collection will be populated with the data from the server. So simply render the template once data will be fetched:

```
menusCollection.fetch({context: this}).done(function () {
  this.el.innerHTML = _.template(productsTemplate, {data: menusCollection.toJSON()});
});
```

Also you are creating a view with a **wrong** model value - `new ProductsView({model:productsCollection.models});`. It should be a Backbone.Model but in your example it's an array of collection models. If you want to pass a collection to the view use `collection` property name.

If I were you I would write something like this:

```
var ProductsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.menusCollection = options.menusCollection;
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(_.template(productsTemplate, {
            data: this.collection.toJSON(),
            menus: this.menusCollection.toJSON()
        }));
    }
});

app_router.on('route:products', function () {
    var menusCollection = new MenusCollection();
    var productsCollection = new ProductsCollection();

    $.when(menusCollection.fetch(), productsCollection.fetch()).done(function () {
        var productsView = new ProductsView({
            menusCollection: menusCollection,
            collection: productsCollection
        });
        productsView.render();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer... I have error `Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined`

Comment: @Makromat it's because of the context, try `menusCollection.fetch({context: this})`

Comment: Please take a look now I have already products in template rendered. But How Can I render menus as well in same template or view ? Thanks!

Comment: Same way I know render menusCollection but I don't know how both with productsCollection...

Comment: @Makromat see an updated answer. Hope it will be clear to you,